# Better animation for max-height CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So i have created this accordion animation, CSS ONLY

https://codepen.io/ziad-darwich/pen/ExjGxKx

```css
body{
  margin:100px 300px
}
.accordion{
  max-width:400px;
}
.tabs{
  margin:5px 0;
}
.tab-heading{
  background-color:#092e3d;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size:.6em;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
}
.tab-heading h2{
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tab-content {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height:0;
  transition:max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.tab-content p{
  margin:20px;
}
input{
  display:none
}
input:checked + .tab-heading{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
input:checked ~ .tab-content{
  max-height:200px;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab1">
      <h2>Tab 1 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab2">
      <h2>Tab 2 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Nullam consectetur justo ut rutrum venenatis. Maecenas id mollis quam, sit amet venenatis arcu.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab3">
      <h2>Tab 3 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am animating the max-height of the tab content.

So my thing is that if max-height is very big, like max-height:1000px; on closing the tab it takes time to start, i believe because it is basically animating the 1000px; but i want the animation to start directly after it is triggered.

Thank you

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. I'd suggest reducing the max-height to something more reasonable but your only *real*  recourse is javascript to you want to animate the *actual* height.

Comment: yes @Paulie_D i suppose so, but just checking if there's any turnaround so i don't use js

Comment: I don't remember cases, where it was possible without js :( Reasonable `max-height` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay to the `transition` of opening the tab, so the opened one will close a bit earlier and then the next one will open.

```css
body {
  margin: 100px 300px
}

.accordion {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.tabs {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.tab-heading {
  background-color: #092e3d;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: .6em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.tab-heading h2 {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tab-content {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 20px;
}

input {
  display: none
}

input:checked+.tab-heading {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab1">
      <h2>Tab 1 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab2">
      <h2>Tab 2 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in luctus tellus. Nullam consectetur justo ut rutrum venenatis. Maecenas id mollis quam, sit amet venenatis arcu.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3" />
    <label class="tab-heading" for="tab3">
      <h2>Tab 3 Title</h2>
    </label>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how I added a different transition for the `checked` `input`. I've set it to start after the close animation has finished, but you can obviously play with that.

---

**EDIT:**
The transitions are starting at the same time, what happens is that it is invisible until it reaches the element's real height. That's why you are seeing a delay.

Suppose that your element has a `height` of `100px` and you're animating the `max-height` from `200px` to `0`. Until `max-height` reaches `100px`, the animation won't be visible.

For the elements to have a simultaneous transition, you should animate the `height` and not the `max-height`. Then you could still add the `max-height`, but you wouldn't be able to keep whatever the real height is and instead you'd have a fixed one. Supposing that you still want to go `CSS`-only.

Comment: thank you for the comment, my issue that i want both to start together directly on click

Comment: animating height is supposed to know how much height i should go to, since if my content is dynamic and takes like 50px height and im defining a height of 200px to animate to, i would get empty space under it

Comment: That's where javascript comes in handy